Creating a Diary with dates in InDesign: Data Merge - .CSV File keeps duplicating records on left and right pages
I'm currently doing a diary and I've set up an excel file (and exported as .CSV) that contains all information I need, this works perfectly with 1 parent page.
However, I have two parent pages (namely the left and the right pages to accommodate for the inside margins), creating a data merge ends up duplicating the data on both parents before going on to the next line in the record. Multiple Record is greyed out.
The same thing happens when I keep it as only 1 parent with facing pages.
Screenshots: (please ignore the formatting of the Month name etc. the records placeholder names are just longer than the entries themselves)





I found something that worked:
Indesign data merge and facing pages
I just followed this and split my left pages from my right pages in the spreadsheet and inserted them as needed.
i.e: I had all my odd days etc. in one column in the spreadsheet and applied them only in the left pages, and then all my even days etc. in one column in the spreadsheet and applied them only in the right pages.
I hope this helped!
